# Assign clients using the same certificate the same subnet

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I would like to conditionally assign clients a subnet based on what certificate they are using. Each user is given their own certificate and key, but will then use this on all their devices.

The desired end result is that all devices a specific user connects to the server will be able to communicate with each other over the VPN, but will not be able to communicate with other users' devices.

After much Googling, I haven't been able to find a way of configuring OpenVPN to allow this. I'm still currently planning the setup for the server, so if this will be easier with alternative software, I am open to suggestions. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A specific instance of OpenVPN runs with a single configuration file, which in turn can only operate a single TUN/TAP network interface. Asking OpenVPN to operate two interfaces is simply not possible.

However, there is nothing stopping you from creating two OpenVPN instances, each with its own interface, listening on different ports (the number 1194 is not a formal standard, any port number will do). You can:

- only allow certificates issued by a particular CA to connect to each instance, if you have or can use/configure more than one CA
- configure each instance with separate [TLS-Auth](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#security) files, and share these with the respective clients so that only those with the right file can connect to their own instance
- use the [TLS-Verify](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn24ManPage) functionality to test the certificates yourself, perhaps against a pre-approved list of certificates for each OpenVPN instance, or matching a department in the certificate's Distinguished Name.

For good security, a mix of the above would be even better.